# How can I use Excel VBA to update links when a button is pressed?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making an Excel file where everyone from a team has to copy + paste link a specific row from their Excel files (on SharePoint) to a general Excel file.

The idea is that when someone opens the general Excel the external references to the other Excel files are not updated automatically. The rationale behind this is that when new files have to be added to the general file (or removed) it doesn't take too much time. I want to insert a button which has to be pressed once a month to update all the external references so that the general list can be exported.

So far I have not yet succeeded in this.

I have tried multiple things, but in my mind this code should be working

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click()

     ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name = Active.Workbook.LinkSources

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.CalculateBeforeSave = True

End Sub
```

I want to insert a button which has to be pressed once a month to update all the external references so that the general list can be exported.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or is it just not doing anything?

Comment: You appear to have some typos in your `UpdateLink` line. It should probably read: `ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources`

Comment: You're right there were some typos (stupid me). Now the error message is gone and I think it's updating when I press the button. However, the values do not change (only if I press Ctrl+Enter in a cell it updates to the new value for that cell).

Comment: Perhaps because you've turned off Calculation? Hitting Enter in a cell forces *that* cell to be calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some small adjustments it works now. I had typos in the `UpdateLink` line and forgot to add `Calculate`. So the code that works for me is:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

 End Sub

 Private Sub Button_Click()

     ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet123").Calculate

 End Sub

 Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.CalculateBeforeSave = True

End Sub
```